# share enum between python and arduino

Tags: python

I have created a gui in python that allows an arduino controlled mecanum wheel cart to move around.

The cart allows for 8 different move directions and can rotate left and right. Commands are sent over a serial connection between the laptop(w10, python) and the arduino.

I have an Enum class in python representing the different move directions.

I have a corresponding enum in the arduino to interprete the commands from the python task.

What is an easy way to share a single common enum definition for both coding environments?

Comment: You mean simple code-sharing between two pieces of source code in differing languages? You'll have to find some common ground between them.

Comment: You mean copy and past the text (the enum list) between the two?  I found a great thread that talks about Python enums specifically.  But even with the slightly different syntax of all the different options in Python, I still see slight differences that will likely prevent cutting and pasting w/o modification.  Ask and I'll post that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

One approach that I have used for similar purposes is to generate the appropriate header files (or module or whatever) from a simple text file for all the required uses.

Since you already know python this should be pretty easy. Quick "proof of concept" follows. (Warning: I barely know any python.)

One downside to this is that you have to remember to regenerate the header/module each time you update the enum (keys or values) - don't forget to recompile for the C++ part. If you have a build system, it is best to integrate that code generation step into it.

A variation of this is to parse one of the language's source code to extract the definition and output it in a format suitable for the other. That is generally much harder to do though if you want to make it robust.

---

#### robot.enum

```
UP    1
DOWN  2
LEFT  3
RIGHT 4
JUMP  5
```

#### enum_generator.py

```python
def python_enum(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as w:
        w.write('class Robot(Enum):\n')
        with open('robot.enum') as r:
            for line in r:
                parts = line.split()
                w.write(f'    {parts[0]} = {parts[1]}\n')

def cplusplus_enum(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as w:
        w.write('#pragma once\n')
        w.write('enum Robot: int {\n')
        with open('robot.enum') as f:
            for line in f:
                parts = line.split()
                w.write(f'  {parts[0]} = {parts[1]},\n')
        w.write('};');

python_enum('robot_enum.py')
cplusplus_enum('robot_enum.h')
```